# How could Major Cage be reset and experience the victory?

Tags: ending, edge-of-tomorrow

At the end of *Edge of Tomorrow* Cage kills an Alpha and the Omega. And through that action resets time a day earlier, to the moment he still had to visit the general. But when he awakes in the helicopter, he finds out that the aliens are defeated. How come? Because the moment he killed the Omega is/was after he arrived in the helicopter in London.